# Check Oauth2 token exists and valid in Node.js Rest Client With Bluebird

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, bluebird

I am writing a Node.js client for a REST API that uses OAuth2. I am using Bluebird and promises (and sending the access token in the header) and I was wondering when would be a good time to check if the access token is already granted (exists) or still valid (not expired).

So far, I have come up with this:

```
'use strict';

var Bluebird = require('bluebird');
var request = Bluebird.promisifyAll(require('request'), { multiArgs: true });
var Oauth = require('oauth');
var OAuth2 = OAuth.OAuth2;
var _ = require('lodash');

function Client(options) {

    this.options = _.assign({
        url: '<API URL>',
        oauth2Url: 'oauth2/token',
        apiVersion: process.env.apiVersion,
        consumerKey: process.env.consumerKey,
        consumerSecret: process.env.consumerSecret
    }, options);

    if (!this.options.url) {
        throw new Error('Missing client url.');
    }

    ...

    if (!this.options.consumerSecret) {
        throw new Error('Missing consumer secret.');
    }


    if(!this.access_token){
        var oauth2 = new OAuth2(
            this.options.consumerKey,
            this.options.consumerSecret,
            this.options.url + this.options.version,
      null,
            this.options.oauth2Url,
            null);
        oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken(
       '',
       {'grant_type':'client_credentials'},
       function (e, access_token, refresh_token, results){
                 this.access_token = access_token;
                 this.refresh_token = refresh_token;
       done();
     });
    }

}

Client.prototype.queryApi = function (options, callback) {
    return request.postAsync({
        headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
    },
        url: this.options.url + this.options.apiVersion,
        body: JSON.stringify(options)}).
        then(function (result) {
            var json = JSON.parse(result[1]);

            if (_.isFunction(callback)) {
                callback(null, json);
            }
            return json;
        }).
        catch(function (err) {
            if (_.isFunction(callback)) {
                callback(err);
                return;
            }
            throw err;
        });
};

module.exports = Client;
```

I am new to both Oauth/Oauth2 and Node.js and I was just wondering if I am checking for the access token in the right place and how/where can I also check if it expired or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is two way to check whether access token is expired or not

- By knowing token_expiration value from your oauth app.In this case you need to keep task running on your app that will determine wheter access_token is expired or not.(Not recommended way of handling access token)
- Handle the response from Authorization server stating that your acces token has been expired.In this case you need to get new access token by presenting refresh token.

You can write 'tokenPersistanceFunction' that will be called when your oauth values(access_token,refresh_token) are updated.

I have modified your code to reflect these changes

```
    function tokenPersistanceFunction(updatedOauth){

        // Here you will get Updated Oauth values 
        // Save these to DB
        return saveAccessToken(updatedOauth.access_token, updatedOauth.refresh_token);
    }

    Client.prototype.queryApi = function (options, tokenPersistanceFunction, callback) {
        return request.postAsync({
            headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
            url: this.options.url + this.options.apiVersion,
            body: JSON.stringify(options)}).
            then(function (result) {

                // You have some indication from your oauth server, that your access_token is expired.
                // You can check your response here to know whether access_token is expired or not.

                // If access_token is expired, Make request to refresh access token.
                // In your case 
                if(AccessTokenIsExpired){
                    // Function that will make request to refresh access_token by presenting refresh_token
                    return <functionThatRefreshesAccessToken>( refreshAccessTokenOptions,tokenPersistanceFunction)
                  .then(function(result){

                      //Extract access_token, refresh_token from response
                      // call 'tokenPersistanceFunction' to store these token in your DB.

                      return tokenPersistanceFunction(updatedOauth);

                  })
                  .then(function(savedOauthTokensSuccess){
                      // Now you have the updated Oauth tokens, you can make request to get resource
                      // this call will return you the actual response.
                      return queryApi(options, tokenPersistanceFunction, callback);
                  })
                }else{
                  var json = JSON.parse(result[1]);

                if (_.isFunction(callback)) {
                    callback(null, json);
                }
                return json;
                }


            }).
            catch(function (err) {
                if (_.isFunction(callback)) {
                    callback(err);
                    return;
                }
                throw err;
            });
    };
```